# Symfony Form Theming: Override country choice option template

Tags: php, forms, symfony, internationalization, theming

I have a form that renders a country select like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="form[country]" class="its--col-sm-2 control-label">{{ form_label(form.country) }}</label>
    <div class="its--col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.country, { 'attr':{'id': 'countryForm', 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem comes with [AOTranslationBundle](https://github.com/adrianolek/AOTranslationBundle).

It's a great bundle. Registers in db all translations that are being rendered in your view and show them in the toolbar for translation.

Then, symfony's [country choice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/country.html) tries to translate all countries that [Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/country.html) returns.

I solved this overriding *choice_widget_options*

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{%- block choice_widget_options -%}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        <option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_options -%}
```

My question is... How can i override just country select options and not other select options?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override for that particular field only.

You can try this approach.
[Customize individual field](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)